# Attributed String only to change Font Size, not the font name

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to set attributed text to a label. However, I want to change the size but not want to set the font name, how do I do that?

```
let myAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some Text",
 attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia",size: 18.0)!])
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this,

```
Your_Label.font.withSize(20)
```

Your end string will be,

```
let myAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some Text", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:Your_Label.font.withSize(15)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the font name from label.

```
let myAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some Text", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: label.fontName, size: 18.0)!])
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 Extension for changing just the font size in an NSMutableAttributedString

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    
    /// Changes just the font size of an attributed string, while keeping all other attributes.
    func changFontSizeTo(fontSize: Int) {
        let attributes = self.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil)
        
        guard let font = attributes[NSAttributedString.Key.font] as? UIFont else { return }
        let newFont = font.withSize(CGFloat(fontSize))
        
        self.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: newFont], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.string.count))
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

UIFont has an instance method [withSize(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/1619032-withsize), returns a new font that is identical to the current font except the specified size.

Try it to update size of your font.

```
let label = UILabel()
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
let labelFont = label.font.withSize(20)
```

Swift 3:

```
let myAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some Text", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:labelFont])
```

Swift 4:

```
let myAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some Text", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:labelFont])
```

[image]